# How to use modal dialog as login system im using bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to do is make a login system with single page website using modal dialog as login form and if the user successfully login it will direct to Profile Form using show/hide javascript script.

My problem is in my current code on modal dialog for login is not working. Every-time i click the login button nothing happens. Anyone here know how to make my it work?

[image]

index.php

```
<?php 
include_once('myIncludes.php');
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined" && sessionStorage.getItem('pageToShow')) {
        var pageToShow = sessionStorage.getItem('pageToShow');
         $('.page').addClass('hide');
         $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
    }
    $('.show-page').click(function(){
        var pageToShow = $(this).data('page');
         $('.page').addClass('hide');
         $('.' + pageToShow).removeClass('hide');
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
            sessionStorage.setItem('pageToShow', pageToShow);
        }

    $('.modal-btn').click(function() {
        $('.modal').modal('hide');
    });
});  
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#login").click( function(){
        if($("#lemail")).val() == "" || $("#lpassword").val() == "") {
            window.alert("Please enter both email and Password");
        }else{
            $.POST($("#elogForm").attr("action"),
                    $("#elogForm :input").serializeArray(),
                    function(data) {
                    window.alert(data);
                    });
            );
        }
        $("#elogForm").submit( function() {
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>

<form method="post" id="elogForm" action="index.php">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h5 class="modal-title">PLEASE ENTER YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS AND PASSWORD TO LOG IN.</h5>            
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-horizontal" id="loginform">        
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="email" id="lemail" name="email" value="<?php echo $unm ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email Address..." required="required" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                                    <input type="password" id="lpassword" name="password" value="<?php echo $pwd ?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Password..." required="required" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="staylogged" class="checkbox-inline" />
                                                <label>  &nbsp; Keep me logged in</label>  &nbsp; <b>|</b>
                                                <a href="" style="text-decoration:none">  &nbsp; Forgot your password?</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                                <button type="button" id="login" name="login" class="btn btn-primary show-page modal-btn"  data-page="Profile"  data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="container">
        <div class="page Home">
            <div class="row">
                <center>    
                    <h1>"Home"</h1>
                </center>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="page Profile hide">
            <div class="row">
                <center>
                    <h1>"Profile"</h1>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

connection.php

```
<?php
class Connection{
    public function dbConnect(){
        return new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', 'root', '');
    }
}
?>
```

myIncludes.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
include_once('connection.php');
include_once('user.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $user = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $object = new User();
    $object->Login($user, $pass);
}
?>
```

user.php:

```
    <?php
    include_once('connection.php');
    class User{

        private $db;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->db = new Connection();
            $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
        }
        public function Login($user, $pass){
            if(!empty($user) && !empty($pass)){
                $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * from user WHERE email=? AND password=?");
                $st->bindParam(1, $user);
                $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
                $st->execute();

                if($st->rowCount() == 1){
                    echo "User verifies, Access granted";
                } else {
                    echo "Incorrect Email or Password";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Please enter Email and Password";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

error i got in console:

[image]

Comment: have you checked console log for errors? I'm pretty sure that there is no such `$.POST` - *uppercase* method in jQuery, unless you have overridden with your own.

Comment: @code-jaff i get that jquery code on a youtube tutorial but it seems not working :(

Comment: make it lower case one `$.post`, and monitor javascript terminal log for errors. You'll get some idea about from where the error propagates.

Comment: @code-jaff here is the error i got in the console i posted in my question.

Comment: There's a lot of confusing stuff going on here.  You have the data-dismiss set on the login button, plus you have a click handler that is doing the same.  Then you have a click handler for the same button that seems to be serializing the data and displaying in an alert, but I don't see that you're submitting it, because you have another submit handler that is returning false.  Maybe start from scratch and add the pieces to accomplish each task in sequence.  Get one part working and move to the next.  Ask questions when you get stuck on a specific task.